# How can I create an Observer over a dynamic list in RxJava?

Tags: rx-java

I need to create an Observer over an array which is constantly changing (adding elements).

I am using Obserable.from(Iterable) but it seems that it creates the Observable over the ArrayList as it is at the moment of the creation.

I need the Observer to be notified and the Action to be executed everytime the ArrayList gets a new element added.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There you go. Thanks to Dávid Karnok on RxJava Google Group

```scala
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.subjects.PublishSubject;

public class ObservableListExample {

    public static class ObservableList<T> {

        protected final List<T> list;
        protected final PublishSubject<T> onAdd;

        public ObservableList() {
            this.list = new ArrayList<T>();
            this.onAdd = PublishSubject.create();
        }
        public void add(T value) {
            list.add(value);
            onAdd.onNext(value);
        }
        public Observable<T> getObservable() {
            return onAdd;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObservableList<Integer> olist = new ObservableList<>();

        olist.getObservable().subscribe(System.out::println);

        olist.add(1);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        olist.add(2);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        olist.add(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have this example in scala?

Comment: No sir. Not yet. I'll do it and let you know :)

Comment: Great answer, I found this very useful. I extended your solution with update() and remove() methods: https://gist.github.com/mauricegavin/fae0081c056327958ef4

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If you want the Observable to emit one onNext with the current state of the list when one Observer subscribes to it, you can use a BehaviourSubject.

Comment: Will it work if one only uses private static PublishSubject<List<T>> publishListSubject instead?

Answer (score 5):

I would consider this approach based on BehaviourSubject.
This differs from juanpavergara's solution in that an onNext() will be immediately emitted to the Observer when subscribing to the Observable.

```
public class ObservableList<T> {

    protected final List<T> list;
    protected final BehaviorSubject<List<T>> behaviorSubject;

    public ObservableList(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
        this.behaviorSubject = BehaviorSubject.create(list);
    }

    public Observable<List<T>> getObservable() {
        return behaviorSubject;
    }

    public void add(T element) {
        list.add(element);
        behaviorSubject.onNext(list);
    }
}


private void main() {
    final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(0);
    list.add(1);

    final ObservableList<Integer> olist = new ObservableList<>(list);

    olist.getObservable().subscribe(System.out::println);

    olist.add(2);
    olist.add(3);
}
```

This solution may be useful when implementing MVP, when you want to observe one resource (ie: a list of objects) returned by one component in the system (ie: one repository or DataSource), and you want the Observer (ie: Presenter or Interactor) to be notified when an element is added to the list in another part of the system.

Comment: Why do you use BehaviorSubject but not ReplaySubject? Don't you miss elements of the list that were added before subscribing?

Comment: @fdermishin `onNext()` gets the whole list, not just the added element. So you'll get the current state of the list when you subscribe.

Comment: I get `reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that List<T> conforms to ObservableOnSubscribe<T>` on `.create(list)`

Answer (score 4):

You can merge two observables to one.
One of them can be initial list of elements and second can be subject:

```
import rx.Observable;
import rx.subjects.ReplaySubject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ExampleObservableList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> initialNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        initialNumbers.add(1);
        initialNumbers.add(2);

        Observable<Integer> observableInitial = Observable.from(initialNumbers);
        ReplaySubject<Integer> subject = ReplaySubject.create();

        Observable<Integer> source = Observable.merge(observableInitial, subject);

        source.subscribe(System.out::println);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            subject.onNext(i);
        }
    }

}
```

If you don't have initial elements you can use only `ReplaySubject` (or other `Subject` -> see http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReplaySubject<Integer> source = ReplaySubject.create();
    source.subscribe(System.out::println);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        source.onNext(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi you can use ObservableRxList to observable on addAll, add, remove and update list

```
public class ObservableRxList<T> {
    protected final List<T> list;
    protected final PublishSubject<List<T>> subject;

     public ObservableRxList() {
         this.list = new ArrayList<T>();
         this.subject = PublishSubject.create();
     }

     public void add(T value) {
         list.add(value);
         subject.onNext(list);
     }

     public void addAll(List<T> value) {
         list.addAll(value);
         subject.onNext(list);
     }

     //not sure about this
     public void update(T value) {
         for (ListIterator<T> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
             if (value == it.next()) {
                 it.set(value);
                 break;
             }
         }
         subject.onNext(list);
     }

     public void update(int position, T value) {
         list.set(position, value);
         subject.onNext(list);
     }

     public void remove(T value) {
         list.remove(value);
         subject.onNext(list);
     }

     public void remove(int index) {
         list.remove(index);
         subject.onNext(list);
     }

     public Observable<List<T>> getObservable() {
         return subject;
     }

     public List<T> getCurrentList() {
         return list;
     }
 }
```

usage:
every time use addAll, add, remove or update this observer will fire with whole updated list

```
mObservableRxList.getObservable().subscribe(productList-> {
    this.products.clear();
    this.products.addAll(productList;
    productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
});
```