# RxJava: Watch for set to reach 0 elements

Tags: java, rx-java

What is the RxJava idiomatic way to discover when a Set has reached 0 elements?

I have looked at this answer: [How can I create an Observer over a dynamic list in RxJava?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816691/how-can-i-create-an-observer-over-a-dynamic-list-in-rxjava), and I can see how I could wrap a `HashSet` with a custom `ObservableHashSet`, and then in the remove() method, if the size is 0, call `onCompleted`.

Is that the proper way?  Is there a simpler/built-in approach?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much.

Although you could write a decorator, and delegate unmodified methods unchanged. Then you can use it on `TreeSet` etc.

Also, perhaps you could just add `sizeAsObservable()` (size() is taken):
And then you can filter that.

```
class ObservableSet implements Set<T> {
    private final Set<T> set;
    private final BehaviorSubject<T> sizeSubject = BehaviorSubject.create(); // 

    public ObservableSet(Set<T> set) {
        this.set = set;
        subject.onNext(set.size());
    }

    public Observable<Integer> sizeAsObservable() {
        return sizeSubject.asObservable();
    }

    public add(T t){
        set.add(t);
        sizeSubject.onNext(set.size());
    }

    ...
}
```

...and just filter for 0 if you just want the empties, and skip the first result, as you said you were interested only in when the set becomes empty.

`obsSet.sizeAsObservable().skip(1).filter(size -> size == 0)`

Otherwise if you have control over removals, just check then or track it there!

Answer (score 0):

See [Blocking Observable Operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Blocking-Observable-Operators) wiki page of rxJava.

By using **[first( )](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/first.html)** and **[firstOrDefault( )](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/first.html)** ,you can:

- **first( )** — block until the Observable emits an item, then return the first item emitted by the Observable
- **firstOrDefault( )** — block until the Observable emits an item or completes, then return the first item emitted by the Observable or a default item if the Observable did not emit an item

I hope it's helps you.

Comment: Thanks @pRaNaY, probably due to my newness to RxJava, I don't see how to use your suggestion in solving the question.

Comment: I can't see how it helps either.