# Android - Add new Items to MutableLiveData and observe

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

How can I add new Items to a MutableLiveData List? I want to build an infinite scrolling Recyclerview. So I have a List with 10 items and after clicking a "load more button" I want to add ten new Items.

This are my lists of products:

```
private companion object {
        private var _products = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Product>>()
    }

    val products: LiveData<MutableList<Product>> = _products
```

Ant this is my loading function:

```
fun loadProducts(category: Category) { // category: String
        _isViewLoading.postValue(true)


        AppService.fetchProducts(category, neuheitenCounter) { success, response ->
            _isViewLoading.postValue(false)
            if(success) {
                when(category) {
                    Category.NEWS -> {
                        if(_products.value == null) {
                            _products.value = response?.products //as List<Product>
                        } else {
                            response?.let {
                                _products.value?.addAll(response?.products)
                            }
                        }

                        neuheitenCounter++
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If I call `_products.value = response?.products` it fires the observe method in my Activity. But if I call `addAll` or `add`, the observer method is not called.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notify Observer when item is added to List of LiveData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941537/notify-observer-when-item-is-added-to-list-of-livedata)

Comment: I think it is not correct. They said addAll and set the list to the new one. I just want to add new items without adding the complete list / override the existing one because I make changes via Adapter and it will be removed if I add a complete new list.

Comment: It's usual way of updating the RecycleView. I've added an answer with more details, I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it's how you should update the adapter

1. Add new items to the existing list
2. Notify LiveData by assigning the same list to its value. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49022687/4858777) is the same question with the solution.
3. When your Activity is notified that the list is changed, it should notify the adapter about the changes by calling its [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) method.

When you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method of the adapter, it compares previous items with the new ones, figures out which of them are changed and updates the RecyclerView. You can help the adapter by calling [notifyItemRangeInserted()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeInserted(int,%20int)) instead of `notifyDataSetChanged()`. `notifyItemRangeInserted()` accepts a range on inserted items, in your case you can calculate it but taking the difference between `adapter.itemCount` and the `productList.size`.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. Sorry. Didnt know that the adapter is so smart that it figures out which of them are changed. 

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

> MutableLiveData.postValue(T value)

Answer (score 0):

I had that same issue .I copied data of `LiveData` in new `List` then i added `new data` to `new List`.And assigned `new List` to `LiveData`.I know this not exact SOLUTION but this solved problem.

Try this.

```
    var tempList= _products.value
    tempList.addAll(response?.products)
    _products.value = tempList
```

I hope this will help you.