# Twitter Streaming API HTTP 420

Tags: android, kotlin, streaming, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack

**I want to consume twitter streaming api in android.**

I've used kotlin coroutines and retrofit.

Somehow in the third request i get an **HTTP 420 ERROR (Enhance your calm)**

I cannot understand why this happens. I am using kotlin coroutines.

Here's my code:

```
    fun getStreamData(str: String) {
        Log.d("debug", "Fetching data..")
        coroutineScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                //Display loading animation in UI
                _status.value = DataApiStatus.LOADING
            }
            try {
                val listResult = ApiService().api!!.getTweetList(str).await()

                while (!listResult.source().exhausted()) {
                    val reader = JsonReader(InputStreamReader(listResult.byteStream()))
                    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484353/gson-throws-malformedjsonexception
                    reader.setLenient(true);
                    val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                    val j = gson.fromJson<JsonObject>(reader, JsonObject::class.java)

                    Log.d("debug", "JSON: " + j.toString())

                    if (j.get("text") != null && j.getAsJsonObject("user").get("profile_image_url_https") != null && j.getAsJsonObject("user").get("name") != null){
                        val t = gson.fromJson<Tweet>(j, Tweet::class.java)

                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                            _status.value = DataApiStatus.DONE
                            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941537/notify-observer-when-item-is-added-to-list-of-livedata
                            tweetsList.add(t)
                            _tweetsList.value = tweetsList
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (e : JsonSyntaxException) {
                Log.e("error", "JsonSyntaxException ${e.message}");
            }
            catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("error", "ERROR ${e.message}")
            }
        }
    }
```

This function is responsible to search the stream accordingly to *str* string which is a parameter.
Also, when the search parameter changes i cancel the current job and relaunch a new one with the actual search parameter.

```
fun cancelJob(){
        Log.d("debug", "Cancelling current Job!")
        coroutineScope.coroutineContext.cancelChildren()
    }
```

What am i doing wrong? In the third request i get an HTTP 420 ERROR.

Here's the full code:

https://github.com/maiamiguel/RHO-Challenge

Answer (score 1):

The 420 Enhance Your Calm status code is an unofficial extension by Twitter. Twitter used this to tell HTTP clients that they were being rate limited. Rate limiting means putting restrictions on the total number of requests a client may do within a time period.

Comment: Thanks. what i don't understand is why i get a HTTP 420, once i am cancelling the coroutine context when the search parameter changes.

Comment: It is not your code buddy. For instance, if you type 3-4 characters at the same time. In that case, it will call the API 3-4 times at the same time. This might be resulting in HTTP 420 because API is being called so many time. Hope you got my point.

Comment: I've switched to callbacks and it works just fine. I can change my search parameter multiple times and it works well. I don't get the HTTP 420 on third request. On the other hand, with deffered or observable in retrofit, on the third request i get an error (HTTP 420). Any idea why? Thanks :)