# Kotlin MVVM with Firebase not Observing data when added to MutableLiveData Array

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, mvvm

I have a bottom Sheet Fragment with MVVM which is observing a Firebase Search which is then added to a MutableLiveData.

The .observe(viewLifecycleOwner){it->} is never accessed when data is set from the firebase search even when data is added to the MutableLiveData

```
private var QrcodeSearch: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<FBAccountNameModel>> = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<FBAccountNameModel>>()
```

```
   fun QrCodeScanSearch(QRCode: String) {
        val profile = ArrayList<FBAccountNameModel>()
        db.collection("UserProfiles").orderBy("UserUUID")
            .startAt(QRCode)
            .endAt("$QRCode\uf8ff")
            .limit(5)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
                if (snapshot != null) {
                    Log.d("QRSearchProfileAll", "${snapshot.documents}")
                    val document = snapshot.documents
                    document.forEach {
                        val groupUser = it.toObject(FBAccountNameModel::class.java)
                        Log.d("QrUser", groupUser.toString())
                        if (groupUser != null) {
                            Log.d(
                                "QrSearchProfile",
                                groupUser.UserEmail + " " + groupUser.Username + " " + groupUser.UserUUID
                            )
                            profile.add(groupUser)
                        }
                    }
                    QrcodeSearch.value = profile
                }
            }
    }
```

The query from firebase is being received as the correct data is Logged into logCat

```
 internal  var qrcodeSearch:MutableLiveData<ArrayList<FBAccountNameModel>>
        get() { return QrcodeSearch}
        set(value) {QrcodeSearch =  value}
```

```
groupViewModel.qrcodeSearch.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){it ->
            Log.d("QRCodeSearch Observed Data",it.toString())

        }
```

The Observation of the data is never accessed and im unsure where to go even when the MuttableLiveData has data set from .value = , I have also tried *.postValue()

Comment: Have you tried to add a failure listener to see if something goes wrong?

Comment: The Retrieval of the data works its the Observation of the array wont update

Answer (score 0):

The `observer` will not get notified if you add a list, because `LiveData` keeps track of each change as a version number simple counter stored as an `int`.

Calling `setValue()` increments this version and updates any observers with the new data only if the observer's version number is less than the `LiveData`'s version,

the side effect is if the `LiveData`'s underlying data structure has changed (such as adding an element to a Collection), nothing will happen to communicate this to the observers.

My Solution is just simple call `.toList()`

```
// here
QrcodeSearch.value = profile.toList()
...
```

here is the another answer
[Notify Observer when item is added to List of LiveData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941537/notify-observer-when-item-is-added-to-list-of-livedata)

Comment: QRcodeSearch.value = profile.toLisst(),  won't work as profile is an ArrayList already

Comment: Ive attempted the .notifyObserver but still doesnt work

Comment: "QRcodeSearch.value = profile.toLisst(), won't work as profile is an ArrayList already"
It is better to return a `List` rather than `ArrayList` because `ArrayList` is also implements the `List` interface

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would use MutableLiveData to modify the data, but use LiveData to observe that data. So can have live data variable pointing to mutable variable.

```
private var _liveData: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<FBAccountNameModel>> = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<FBAccountNameModel>>()
val liveData: LiveData<ArrayList<FBAccountNameModel>> = _liveData
```