# How to add items to MutableLiveData arraylist?

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, mutablelivedata

I have a `MainViewModel`with the code:

```
private val locationList: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Location>> = MutableLiveData()
fun getLocationList(): MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Location>> = locationList
```

and a fragment where I am trying to add values to the arraylist, but I don't know how:

```
mainViewModel.getLocationList.value = arrayListof(location) //creates always a new list
```

Maybe someone can help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```kotlin
mainViewModel.getLocationList.value?.add(newLocation)
mainViewModel.getLocationList.value = mainViewModel.getLocationList.value // notify observers
```

Comment: I have tried it, but it doesn't work for me. For example I want the value with `Log.d("location",mainViewModel.getLocationList.value.toString())`, I only get `null` as response.

Comment: Get null before you post a initial value or always null?

Comment: My code looks like this:
 ```mainViewModel.getLocationList.value?.add(newLocation)
mainViewModel.getLocationList.value = mainViewModel.getLocationList.value 
Log.d("location",mainViewModel.getLocationList.value.toString())
```

Comment: You should assign a empty list first, or assign a list contains newLocation when the value is null.

Comment: Maybe you can get more information in this question 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941537/notify-observer-when-item-is-added-to-list-of-livedata