# Android - How to observe an ArrayList for changes with RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java

How can I use RxJava Observables to listen to changes in an ArrayList until that Object is destroyed? I want to update a database entry according to the contents of an ArrayList so I need to listen to changes, let it be deleting items or adding items to the ArrayList.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816691/how-can-i-create-an-observer-over-a-dynamic-list-in-rxjava

Comment: It is similar, but it offers no guidance in how to implement reactions to removing an item by index, the only way to delete an item would be by value and not by index since you just call onNext(T value) on the publishsubject

Comment: You can always encapsulate the operation and pass it to the onNext call.