# Using RxJava to observe List "add" and "remove" actions

Tags: java, android, list, rx-java, addition

I'd like to know if is possible to use RxJava to get updates on a List (more specifically, an ArrayList).
What I want is to have n subscribers that get updates when the list has an item added or removed. I need to know what the action has been, not only the item that was modified.

I've tried searching for this, but so far the closest thing I've found is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28835815/8133711)

However, this only covers the "add" function, not the "remove"...

Something nice would be to have a function `onAdd(Item item)` called when an item is added to the list, and then another one `onRemove(Item item)` when it gets removed.

If this is not the proper way to use RxJava please tell me, I'm learning and accept all kind of help/criticism :)

Thanks,
Iscle

Comment: Can't you modify it yourself and create `remove` based on how `add` is done?

Comment: Sure! I though of doing that, but then I'd need to subscribe to two Observables... Is that a good solution? 

Since I'm doing it on Android, I ended up using local broadcasts while I look for a better way.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do it. One way is to add a second observable, which should be pretty easy. The second option is to pass the operation every time there's a notification.

For example (using lombok to generate constructors, getters, etc):

```java
public class ObservableListExample {

    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class ObservableList<T> {

        protected final List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        protected final PublishSubject<Notification<T>> onChange = PublishSubject.create();

        public void add(T value) {
            list.add(value);
            onChange.onNext(new Notification<T>(Operation.ADD, value));
        }

        public void remove(T value) {
            list.remove(value);
            onChange.onNext(new Notification<T>(Operation.REMOVE, value));
        }

        public Observable<Notification<T>> getObservable() {
            return onChange;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObservableList<Integer> olist = new ObservableList<>();

        olist.getObservable().subscribe(n -> System.out.println("op: " + n.getOperation() + " i: " + n.getItem()));

        olist.add(1);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        olist.add(2);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        olist.add(3);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        olist.remove(2);
    }

    public static enum Operation {
        ADD,
        REMOVE
    }

    @Getter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class Notification<T> {
        private Operation operation;
        private T Item;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
op: ADD i: 1
op: ADD i: 2
op: ADD i: 3
op: REMOVE i: 2
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this solution in mind :D 
However, I think I might go with akarnokd's solution since it looks a bit cleaner to me.